# Hover Zoom-in and Zoom-out Background Not Working Correctly

Tags: html, css

I'am trying to add hover effect to image for zoom in and out. But instantly working zoom out effect without move mouse pointer over the image.

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  height: 100%;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.image:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  transition: .5s ease;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <h2>Slide in Overlay from the Bottom</h2>
  <p>Hover over the image to see the effect.</p>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://www.activeconnections.org/wp-content/uploads/avatar-1.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="text">Hello World</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Actually I want add hover effect to image which when mouse pointer come on the image it going zoom in smoothly and when mouse pointer move over the image, it going zoom out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you want the zoom-in to happen when the mouse hovers over the card, and zoom-out to happen as soon as the mouse moves out from the card. If that is the case, the snippet below should be a fix for this issue:

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  width: 50%;
}

.image {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: black;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  transition: .5s ease;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.container:hover .overlay {
  height: 100%;
}

.text {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-align: center;
}

.container:hover .image {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  transition: .5s ease;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <h2>Slide in Overlay from the Bottom</h2>
  <p>Hover over the image to see the effect.</p>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://www.activeconnections.org/wp-content/uploads/avatar-1.png" alt="Avatar" class="image">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="text">Hello World</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

The problem was with the fact, that you reacted on the `:hover` of the `.image`, and since there was an overlay, once the overlay obscured the image, the css engine removes the `:hover` from the image. Changing the target of the `:hover` to the `.container` makes sure that it will be present even if the overlay obscures the image.

Answer (score 0):

It zooms out when the overlay reaches your pointer. When the overlay reaches your pointer it's actually the overlay that gets the hover effect and no longer the image.

You can avoid this by adding `.pointer-events: none` to your `.container:hover .overlay` css, like this:

```
.container:hover .overlay {
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```